# How to get 50 Hz sine wave from inverter bridge driving PWM pins of MCU

Tags: pic, pwm, filter, inverter, low-pass

I am using this circuit to see the sine wave coming from a DsPIC Pins to check the shape of sine wave created from my sine table. PWM frequency is 18 kHz

[image: This circuit]

But the sine wave does not seem to be not filtered properly. Also it seems to pick up some other noise or making its own oscillations when connecting the debugger to PC.

How should be the calculations or value for this filter or is there any other better options to see the sine-wave from my PWM output pins?

Image added. Below is the ground referenced Waveform on Pins
[image]

Comment: This cannot be answered without understanding the sequencing and voltage levels on L1,2 and H1,2 relative to each other. You should also not connect a scope to anything other than a single-ended, ground referenced signal without special apparatus.

Comment: Each PWM Pin is switching between ground and 3.3Volts. Both PWMs run on central aligned, Pins in complement mode,  PWM  with 50% duty cycle which creates effective duty cycle as 0. Then sine point value is scaled  and added to One PWM and subtracted from the other PWM which creates an effective duty cycle which updated in 360 equally spaced points in 20millisecond Sine wave.

Comment: Draw a picture.

Comment: Better yet, show us the actual waveforms you're getting on the four PWM pins, as well as the composite waveform you're seeing across the capacitor. On the face of it, it seems odd to connect H1 and L1 to opposite sides of the capacitor, but perhaps there's something funny going on with respect to the polarity of the drive signals. Also, the cutoff frequency of your filter is about 480 Hz, which is going to pass a lot of 50 Hz harmonics, distorting your waveform.

Answer (score 1):

Try filtering separately, only `H1`, for example. If you get results, `L1` should give the 180 degrees version, while `H2` and `L2` should give similar results. This looks like a 3-level PWM, so coupling `H1` to `H2` with the RC filters, and `L1` to `L2` should give you the two point differential filtering necessary to reconstruct your signal, `V(H1_H2) - V(L1_L2)`. Here's a quick'n'dirty simulation showing what you tried and what I mentioned (please note that I am making an assumption about the PWM, I don't know what you have there):

[image: test]

Comment: Let me try this method. btw may I know how that simulation model created for that PWM? I was never able to figure out how I can create that PWM pins in Multisim

Comment: @user2454516 I used LTspice, but most simulators should have some ideal comparator, or similar. That's the role of `A1` and `A2`, even if they are actually Schmitt triggers. In rest, sine source (`0.8V@50Hz`) and ramp (`[-1,1]V@18kHz`, plus inversion with `E1`). Don't forget that I *assumed* a three-level PWM, given your simplistic drawings of waveforms. If it's some other type, all bets may be off.

Comment: I think my PWM is different from what I have communicated. This arrangement is not giving that waveform I am looking for . But no problem, as suggested in one of the above rsponse, I have lowered the cut of value to 50hz by replacing the 10nF by 100nF capacitor in my original circuit. Now I can get more stable wave forms. I think this filter I am trying is resonating in 50hz  by picking up 50Hz ripple and creating another waveform which confuses the scope. I need to be more cautious about my power supply and oscilloscope Auto set mechanisms..
Thanks for support

Comment: @user2454516 Hope it works, but, you know, I have to say it: it would have helped much better to use the pictures from the oscilloscope rather than doodling on paper.